# Is there a name of semidirect product of a group with its automorphism group?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, automorphism-groups, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

Consider the construction $G \rtimes \text{Aut}(G)$. Here $
G$ is a group, $\text{Aut}(G)$ is the automorphism group and the semidirect product is over the most obvious action.

1) Is there any name for such a general construction? To me, it seems like the most straight-forward example of a semi-direct product.

2) Are there any surveys over such constructions or any big theorems about the structure of such groups?

3) I'm specifically interested in finding torsional elements when $G = F_2$, the free group of two generators. Is there any result about this special scenario?

Edit: More thoughts about question 3 are below.

As pointed in the comments, if you have any torsional automorphism $\phi$ of the free group (there are good classification theorems for such automorphisms), then a torsional element of the semidirect product will be of the form $(g,\phi)$ such that $g\phi(g)\phi^2(g)... \phi^{k-1}(g)=1$, $k$ being the order of $\phi$.

You can check that any element of the form $(\alpha^{-1} \phi(\alpha),\phi)$ works where $\phi$ is a torsional automorphism and $\alpha \in F_2$. Are these all such elements? Is there a general form of such elements?

Comment: I think it is sometimes called the holomorph (of $G$) in early texts.

Comment: One basic property is that the holomorph $\operatorname{Hol}(G)$ is the normalizer of $G$ in its permutation group under the left regular embedding.  I've only seen it applied in Hopf Galois theory, where one has a bijection between Hopf Galois structures with group $G$ and "regular" embeddings of $G$ in its holomorph [Byott 1999].

Comment: See this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorph_(mathematics)).

Comment: @GeoffRobinson - to my knowledge, it's still called the holomorph. I first met this word in Joseph Rotman's book.

Comment: @benblumsmith :OK, thanks I think the word "holomorph" was used in W. Burnside's famous book (there were editions in 1898 and 1911). It seems that the nomenclature stuck.

Comment: I'm underslept so I can't promise to make any sense, but it seems to me that (in general) the torsion elements in $\operatorname{Hol}(G)$ are the elements $g\phi$ where $\phi$ is a torsion automorphism of $G$, and $g$ has the property that its orbit under the cyclic group generated by $\phi$ has product $1$. E.g. if $G=F_2=\langle x,y\rangle$, then $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ ($y$ fixed) is an automorphism, call it $\phi$, and $x\phi$ is $2$-torsion.

Comment: @benblumsmith, Yes you're making sense. This follows from direct computation. In fact, for any element $\alpha$ of the group and a torsional element $\phi$, the element $\alpha^{-1}  \phi(\alpha)$ is torsional.

I wonder if these are all. I'll edit the question to include this.

Comment: I think you mean $\alpha^{-1}\phi(\alpha)\phi$?

Comment: Seems like "are these all?" is a cohomological question about $G$. Does every $\beta$ satisfying $\beta\beta^\phi\beta^{\phi^2}\dots = 1$ also satisfy $\beta = \alpha^{-1}\phi(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha$? This is a very "is a cocycle a coboundary?" typed question.

Comment: @benblumsmith Ah fantastic! Where can I get to read more on this? It would be very nice if you could write an answer with references.

Comment: It seems to me that @benblumsmith's example of $x\phi$ is not of the form $\alpha^{-1}\phi(\alpha)\phi$ for any $\alpha\in F_2$. This can be seen by taking the exponent of $x$ in $\alpha^{-1}\phi(\alpha)$, which must be even.

Comment: @MarkGrant,
Yes, I agree. Do you have any understanding of the cohomology aspect by @benblumsmith?

Comment: I guess the terminology looks old simply because this construction is not salient in modern developments of group theory.

Comment: Regarding your first question, if $k$ is a field, then the group algebra  $k\big(G \rtimes \text{Aut}(G)\big)$ is isomorphic to the skew group algebra $kG\star \text{Aut}(G)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a first remark, note that if $\tilde{H}\leq G\rtimes \operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is a finite subgroup and $G$ is torsion-free, then the projection $p: G\rtimes \operatorname{Aut}(G)\to \operatorname{Aut}(G)$ maps $\tilde{H}$ isomorphically to some finite subgroup $H=p(\tilde{H})\leq \operatorname{Aut}(G)$.

Now for each finite subgroup $H\leq \operatorname{Aut}(G)$, you can ask yourself what are the subgroups $\tilde{H}\leq G\rtimes \operatorname{Aut}(G)$ projecting to $H$? These correspond to splittings of the semi-direct product $G\rtimes H$, which correspond to $1$-cocycles (or crossed homomorphisms) $f:H\to G$, that is, functions satisfying 
$$
f(ab) = f(a){}^af(b),\quad a,b\in H.
$$ 
Here ${}^ag$ denotes the action of $a$ on $g$. These $1$-cocycles represent elements of the first non-abelian cohomology set $H^1(H;G)$, the trivial element of which is represented by any cocycle of the form $f(a) = (g^{-1}){}^ag$ for some $g\in G$.

So in some sense the answer to your follow-up question lies in the non-abelian cohomolgy of finite subgroups of $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$.

Comment: Thanks. After I was trying to piece together an explanation like this. If we take $H$ to be the cyclic group generated by a single torsional element $\phi \in \text{Aut}(G)$ of order $k$ then any map $f \in H^1(H;G)$ must satisfy $1=f(1)=f(\phi^k) = f(\phi)\  ^{\phi}f(\phi)\  ^{\phi^2}f(\phi)...^{\phi^{k-1}}f(\phi) $. Also, any element of $f \in H^1(H;G)$ is known by the value it takes on $\phi$. So the question really comes down to understanding the non-abelian cohomology of $H$ over $G$.